# Is CGFloat more accurate than Double?

Tags: ios, swift, range, double, cgfloat

Double & CGFloat both print the same value to the console (#2), but only the Double is issued the warning (#1):

(#1) - The warning

[image: the warning]

(#2) - Printing each to the console

```
DOUBLE  = 9.223372036854776e+18
CGFLOAT = 9.223372036854776e+18
```

Many articles mention that a CGFloat is a Float on 32-bit platforms & a Double on a 64-bit platform, but doesn't that only refer to the backing storage? Is there more going on behind the scenes which causes the CGFloat to be more accurate than the Double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, `CGFloat` does not represent a `BigDecimal`-type number, with infinite precision. `CGFloat` [is defined](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ee856f110177289af602c4040a996507f7d1b3ce/Sources/Foundation/CGFloat.swift#L11) as a `struct` with either wraps a `Double` or a `Float`, depending on whether you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform; i.e., on a 64-bit platform, it is **equivalent** to a `Double`, with *no more or less precision or range*.

The difference in the warning you see is that `Double` is a type native to Swift, which the compiler knows about, and has enough information about in order to be able to provide such a warning. `CGFloat`, however, is defined by Apple frameworks, and the compiler does not know enough about it to produce such a warning.

Comment: Sorry Itai, I had just changed the question to 1 I felt was more appropriate.

Comment: @xct789 I think this answer still answers the edited question though - "it is equivalent to a Double, with no more or less precision or range."

Comment: Indeed, I was about to say the same: the answer is just as applicable.